# jQuery UI Droppable and Draggable for Calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I have a calendar package that works pretty well, but I wanted to build another with draggable and droppable elements from jQueryUI.  Just got started, but there is a fiddle here and code below.  There are a couple of issues.  If I set containment to the parent, you cannot apparently drag to a droppable item and it isn't clear to me how jquery positions the dropped elements (as children of the element they are dragged to or just absolutely position relative to the original parent).

I can probably write a function to check for overlapping appointments for the same calendar group, but I would really like to drag and drop elements so that they are children of the target element.

The snippet basically creates an new element where the user clicks on a day and positions that element absolutely relative to the parent, and it allows dragging and resizing inside of the parent, but I would like to drag and drop to another day and make the dropped element a child of the target.  I'll also have to figure out how to get offsets from the parent and heights for the ui objects, but the UI docs have some things about that.

[Old Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5bdj176/1/)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".appointments").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    scope: "day",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
              console.log(event.target.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY);
        console.log(event.target.getBoundingClientRect().left + window.scrollX);
        console.log(Math.floor(ui.helper[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY  - event.target.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY) + "px !important" );
      var ap = ui.draggable;
      $(this).append(ap);
      ap.css({
        top: ap.offset.top + "px",
        left: "0px"
      });
    }
  });
  $(".appointments").click(function(e) {
    const x = e.offsetX;
    const y = e.offsetY;
    console.log(x + ' ' + y);
    newElement = $("<div>", {
      class: "appointment"
    }).css({
      top: y + "px",
      height: "10px",
      background: "blue",
      width: "100%"
    }).appendTo($(this));
    newElement.draggable({
      containment: $("#container"),
      scope: "day"
    });
    newElement.on("resizestop", function(event, ui) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
    newElement.resizable({
      handles: 'n,s',
      minHeight: 1
    });
    newElement.on("resize", function(event, ui) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
    newElement.on("click", function(event, ui) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
    newElement.on("contextmenu", function(e) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("clicked");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.day {

font-size: 14px;
display: inline-block;
background: white;
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px black solid;
text-align: center;
width:20%;
overflow:visible;

}


.week {
font-size:14px;
height:auto;
}


.appointments {

margin-top:10px;
height:108px;  /* 9 hour work day */
position:relative;
}

.dates {
     background: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id = "container">

<div class="week row">
  <div id="2020-01-02" class="day col-xl">
    <span class="calday">Thu, 2020-01-02 </span>
    <div class="appointments">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="2020-01-03" class="day col-xl">
    <span class="calday">Fri, 2020-01-03 </span>
    <div class="appointments">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="2020-01-04" class="day end col-xl">
    <span class="calday">Sat, 2020-01-04 </span>
    <div class="appointments">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="week row">
  <div id="2020-01-02" class="day col-xl">
    <span class="calday">Thu, 2020-01-02 </span>
    <div class="appointments">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="2020-01-03" class="day col-xl">
    <span class="calday">Fri, 2020-01-03 </span>
    <div class="appointments">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="2020-01-04" class="day end col-xl">
    <span class="calday">Sat, 2020-01-04 </span>
    <div class="appointments">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a lot to unpack here. For example, `containment:$(this)` would contain the draggable to the Day. If you want to drag to another day, the containment needs to change at some point. Also Drop has no code bound to it, so when an item is dropped, it's not going to be appended or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".appointments").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    scope: "day",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      // console.log(ui);
      var ap = ui.draggable;
      $(this).append(ap);
      ap.css({
        top: ap.offset.top + "px",
        left: "0px"
      });
    }
  });
  $(".appointments").click(function(e) {
    const x = e.offsetX;
    const y = e.offsetY;
    console.log(x + ' ' + y);
    newElement = $("<div>", {
      class: "appointment"
    }).css({
      top: y + "px",
      height: "10px"
    }).appendTo($(this));
    newElement.draggable({
      containment: $(".row"),
      scope: "day"
    });
    newElement.on("resizestop", function(event, ui) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
    newElement.resizable({
      handles: 'n,s',
      minHeight: 1
    });
    newElement.on("resize", function(event, ui) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
    newElement.on("click", function(event, ui) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
    newElement.on("contextmenu", function(e) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("clicked");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.day {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px black solid;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  overflow: visible;
}

.week {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: auto;
}

.appointments {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 108px;
  /* 9 hour work day */
  position: relative;
}

.appointment {
  position: absolute;
  left: "0px";
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: move;
}

.dates {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="week row">
  <div id="2020-01-02" class="day col-xl">
    <span class="calday">Thu, 2020-01-02 </span>
    <div class="appointments">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="2020-01-03" class="day col-xl">
    <span class="calday">Fri, 2020-01-03 </span>
    <div class="appointments">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="2020-01-04" class="day end col-xl">
    <span class="calday">Sat, 2020-01-04 </span>
    <div class="appointments">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, when a click happens, the new element is created and made draggable, but contained the the Row. So User can drag and drop it in the Day or another day in the same week. Using Offset, we can append the appoint to the new location in the day. This will allow overlap of events, you can adjust the `top` to fit around other items in the same day if you prefer.

Comment: That is excellent.  Little bit of a bug when the height of an element gets to be just a few pixels or less.  You can't actually drag it once the height get too small because the handles are activated instead of the dragger.  There must be some tolerance set to activate the handles ?  And, need to make a few adjustments, but the drag and drop works pretty well.  Thanks.

Comment: @SScotti you can adjust the Resize so that it cannot be made too small. You can also add a Handle to the draggable.

Comment: I edited the question.  Left the old Fiddle, put your code in the snippets with some mods (two rows, container, and containment).  There is an issue with having two rows.  You have to run the snippet in full window to see that.  The top offset is off and it positions it outside of the target.  I played around with getBoundingClientRect to calc a new offset, which seems about right.  Maybe a better way cus that doesn't work, can't set the top position with css for some reason.  Not sure if position abs vs. relative makes any diff here, but thanks.

Comment: Added another Fiddle with full calendar, same problem with dropping in another row, but progress.  https://jsfiddle.net/sscotti/6s4n5fLu/26/